Laravel sanctum during testing: "Session store not set on request."
This error happens very often for people, most of the time because SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS is not set correctly. I did set it correctly for local development but the error happens during testing, e.g.:
tests/foo.test
$response = $this->postJson('/api/auth/register', [...]);

The error: testing.ERROR: Session store not set on request.
What works is, to include the session/cookie middleware manually while testing. But this also shows me that the test requests are not recognized as coming from the frontend:
bootstrap/app.php
                  ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
                      if (app()->environment('testing')) {
                          $middleware->api(prepend: [
                              EncryptCookies::class,
                              StartSession::class,
                          ]);
                      } else {
                          $middleware->statefulApi();
                      }
                  })

This is my phpunit.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory>tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory>tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory>app</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER" value="file"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_STORE" value="array"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS" value="localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8080,::1"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DOMAIN" value="localhost"/>
        <env name="PULSE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>

So my question is: How do I let Laravel Sanctum know that the requests are valid and to initialize the session store during testing?
Edit: The change in bootstrap/app.php works for testing, but it raises an error in development because the app is not fully initialized yet and doesn't know about the environment. It's strange that it works in a test environment though.
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 
Target class [env] does not exist.


Are you using Sanctum::actingAs? Share the test please...

@matiaslauriti No, as this first test was a test for the registration, this was a request for a guest route and this single line was the complete test. I forgot to mention that I am using Pest, not PHPUnit.
